Generate object access keys from props
I have problems with dynamisation in Typescript. I know that TS works statically. However, there are sometimes situations where I want to access an object dynamically and cannot do this directly via any generics because the values are generated. Perhaps you could help me to understand the whole thing a little better. I have the following example:
import React from "react";

const FontTheme = {
  headline: {
    small: { fontSize: 12 },
    medium: { fontSize: 16 },
    large: { fontSize: 20 },
  },

  label: {
    tiny: { fontSize: 4 },
    small: { fontSize: 12 },
  },

  button: {
    small: { fontSize: 12 },
  },
} as const;

interface TextComponentProps {
  variant:
    | "headline-small"
    | "headline-medium"
    | "headline-large"
    | "label-tiny"
    | "label-small"
    | "button-small";
}

function TextComponent({ variant }: TextComponentProps) {
  const [element, size] = variant.split("-");

  const styles = {
    ...FontTheme[element][size],
  };

  console.log(styles);

  return <h1>Text</h1>;
}

export { TextComponent };


Even if I use generics, I could not solve the problem, as the values would be generated by the split method. Is there another way to solve the problem without casting the values? or is it possible to use generics after all?

Since the FontTheme[element][size] will ultimately yield a value, what's the spread { ...FontTheme[element][size] } is supposed to mean? You can't spread values.

Yes you are right, was a small mistake in my example, i have updated it, but the error remains of course the same.

you can solve this problem without casting the value by using Typescript's type inference and generics. This is an example:
import React from "react";

const FontTheme = {
  headline: {
    small: 12,
    medium: 16,
    large: 20,
  },

  label: {
    tiny: 4,
    small: 12,
  },

  button: {
    small: 12,
  },
} as const;

type FontThemeType = typeof FontTheme;
type Variant = `${keyof FontThemeType}-${keyof FontThemeType[keyof FontThemeType]}`;

interface TextComponentProps {
  variant: Variant;
}

function TextComponent({ variant }: TextComponentProps) {
  const [element, size] = variant.split("-") as [keyof FontThemeType, string];

  const styles = FontTheme[element][size as keyof typeof FontTheme[element]];

  console.log(styles);

  return <h1>Text</h1>;
}

export { TextComponent };


Font ThemeType will represents the structure of the FontTheme object
Variant this type uses template literal types to create a union of all possible variant strings.
I hope this sample code and a little explanation will help you. :)

